# Expandir ou Minimizar trecho de código no eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Seria possível minimizar [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] ou expandir [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] **apenas** um trecho de código dentro de um bloco **{...}**, *exemplo abaixo:* [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] utilizando o eclipse IDE?

Comment: Não é só habilitar o *folding*? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21968900

Comment: Sim, é possível! Porém vc só consegue minimizar os métodos de sua classe, conforme imagem anexada.[![exemplo eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4ILy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4ILy.png)

Comment: Salve @hkotsubo! Então, meu folding está ativado mesmo assim não é exibido pra mim a opção de minimizar/expandir meus comentários...

Comment: Bom, o que eu vi aqui é que o Eclipse só habilita o folding se tiver alguma declaração de método logo depois dos comentários. Se tiver comentários "soltos" no código, como no seu exemplo, não aparece o `-` e `+`.

Comment: @hkotsubo, pois bem... A ideia era de minimizar comentários dentro de blocos de código saca? Ao habilitar o folding, eu percebi que conseguira minimizar o javadoc do método, porém, não minimizava código interno do bloco...

Comment: Fiz uns testes aqui e pelo jeito, dentro do corpo de um método o folding não é habilitado. Resumindo: https://ideone.com/N9VrVS - Não sei se é a versão (uso o Neon), ou se tem alguma outra config/plugin, ou se é assim mesmo e não tem jeito.. Enfim, desculpe não poder ajudar mais...

Comment: @hkotsubo valeu, vou continuar pesquisando... Caso eu encontre uma solução, comento aqui! abraços mestre.

Answer (score 3):

Se os eu editor estiver em inglês a opção fica em: Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Folding

Para minimizar todos os trechos de código:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>/</kbd>

Para expandir todos os trechos de código:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>*</kbd>

Comment: Salve mestre Sorack, eu gostaria de expandir e minimizar apenas um trecho de código dentro de um bloco(método, class, etc...), seria apenas um trecho em expecifico.

Comment: Acredito que seja possível, porém ainda não encontrei algo que pudesse ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Mestre, boa noite.

Pelo que pesquisei, realmente não existe uma funcionalidade nativa para o que você quer.

Talvez o mais próximo que você encontre seria algo como as [Regions do C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-region).

Até onde sei, o nosso querido Java não possui a mesma feature. No entanto, encontrei um Plugin para Eclipse IDE que pode ajudar. Trata-se do [Coffee Bytes](https://code.google.com/archive/p/coffee-bytes/), porém o mesmo é descontinuado, então o uso é por sua conta e risco.

Fonte de minha pesquisa: [How to Create a Region in eclipse like Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035646/how-to-create-a-region-in-eclipse-like-visual-studio)

Comment: Show, ao chegar em casa vou fazer o uso desse plugin. Caso funcione como esperado, comento aqui.
Valeu grande!

Comment: Fiquei curioso para saber se resolveu. Conseguiu?

Comment: Cara, não consegui utilizar esse plugin 'Coffe Bytes', você já chegou à usá-lo ?

Answer (score -2):

Você pode colocar um escopo ao redor do que quer minimizar.

```
{

//AQUI VAI O QUE QUER MINIMIZAR

}
```

Note que no lado esquerdo, perto da contagem de linhas, aparecerá um botão com o "-" para você minimizar.

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu a minha pergunta.

Comment: Pensei que sua pergunta era como minimizar um pedaço do texto, no eclipse